# Пожалуйста,объясните как работает этот js код калькулятора

Tags: javascript

Что тут происходит и как это работает?

```
function insert(num) {
  document.querySelector('.output').value = document.querySelector('.output').value+num;
}

function equal() {
  let expresion = document.querySelector('.output').value;

  if(expresion) {
    document.querySelector('.output').value = eval(document.querySelector('.output').value);
  }
}

function clean() {
  document.querySelector('.output').value="";
}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru

Answer (score 1):

Можно предположить, что калькулятор состоит из текстового поля с классом `.output` и кнопок. К кнопкам привязаны функции. В частности:

- `insert(num)` присоединяет строку с числом `num` к уже имеющемуся в текстовом поле значению (то есть из `4` и `2`, например, получается `42`).
- `equal()` заменяет выражение в текстовом поле на результат его исполнения (то есть `2 + 2` заменяет на `4`).
- `clean()` очищает текстовое поле.